# Activity Indicator While Parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, nsxmlparser

The scenario is:

There is a view which has a button that takes user to another view. In the viewDidLoad of the next viewcontroller, a huge XML file gets downloaded, parsed and displayed on the screen. This way, I get the data already displayed on the screen when the view is navigated to it.

The problem is:

When I click on the button that calls the viewcontroller with parsing in it, the application becomes unresponsive. As soon as all the data is downloaded and parsed, the application moves to the next view. Now, I want to show an activity indicator on the click of that button till the time the application is being unresponsive. As soon as the view navigates to the other one, the activity indicator should stop. I tried putting activity indicator in the viewDidLoad of the ViewController I want to land to but to no avail.

PS: I can't do the parsing in the "viewWillAppear" because of some restrictions due to the nature of application.

Looking forward to the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do any major work that doesn't involve the UI in a background queue/thread.

Using GCD, that might look something like this:

```
// Start UIActivityIndicator

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Parse your XML

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Update the UI when you're finished

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really do the parsing on another thread. This way the main thread (which is also the UI thread) can continue. Look at `performSelectorInBackground`.

Your indicator doesn't show up because the parsing probably happens before `viewDidLoad`. You could first add the indicator, then push the new view controller, and then remove the indicator.

But really, this is extremely bad UI and UX design and you should use threading.

Answer (score 1):

You hopefully download the file in the background. If you use a NSOperations for this, you can have that operation also parse the XML file.

This gives you two ways to show progress if you want (better than just a spinner). Allow 50% for the download and 50% for the parsing. When you get the urlConnection delegate response, you can find out how big the download is, then as data comes in update the progress. When you start parsing, you can put some code in parser:didEndElement to ask the parser what line its on, and if you know the total number of lines, you know its progress.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MBProgressHUD here is the link for that.

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uiactivityindicatorview_mbprogresshud/

you have to use this in your viewcontroller viewdidload method.